# I want to split file’s extension by using regular expression

Tags: python

item is a string like "./test/test1.csv" .
I want to change item into "test1".
I wrote code,

```
item=re.search('./*.csv',item)
```

But,"1.csv" is item.I really cannot understand why such a thing happens.What should I do to do my ideal thing?

Comment: Are you aware that you change `item` from a string to a `re` match object?

Comment: `'./*.csv'` does not mean what you think. It's not "dot, slash, any string, dot, csv", but "any char, some slashes, any char csv".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a regex, `'./*.csv'` does not mean what you think it does. A `.` means "any char" and a `*` means "zero or more of what came before", Thus, it's not "dot, slash, any string, dot, csv", but "any char, some slashes, any char csv".

If you really want to use a regex, you could try, e.g., this (among many other variants):

```
>>> re.search(r"([^/]+)\.[^\.]+$", p).group(1)
'test1'
```

Or just use `str.split` and `rsplit`:

```
>>> p.rsplit("/", 1)[-1].split(".")[0]
'test1'
```

Or, since you are handling file paths, how about `os.path`?

```
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.split(p)[1])[0]
'test1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module from the standard library for this kind of filename.

```
import os.path
print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('./test/test1.csv'))[0])
```

In your regular expression version of this, remember that `.` matches *any* character (not just periods), `x*` matches any number of x's (even zero), and that [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will return true if the pattern matches anywhere in the string: your regular expression matches whenever a filename contains the letters "csv" anywhere later than the first or second character.  A correct regular expression implementation might be

```
import re
print(re.search(r'/([^/.]+)\.[^/]+$', './test/test1.csv')[1])
```

(matching a slash, at least one character that is neither a period nor a slash, a period, at least one character that is not a slash, and end of string).  (IMHO `os.path` is more readable and maintainable.)

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
import ntpath
path = ".../test/test1.csv"
file_name = ntpath.basename(path)
```

Comment: why on earth `ntpath`  ? What's wrong with `os.path` ?

Comment: I am just more familiar with this!!

Comment: You shouldn't explicitely import `ntpath` nor `posixpath` unless you really know you want this exact implementation. `os.path` will automagically point to the right 'xxxpath' module for your platform.